# Why don't these 3 links work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

See the yellow section under the pictures that says "Read more about /college/" on http://www.collegeinsideview.com/.

The top 3 links don't work (for Columbia, Princeton and Brown), but the rest do. I'm getting a JS error that says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /columbia/academics/professors/1`. Why is this?

**UPDATE**
After changing the JS from what it was to

```
$('#left > li > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

I don't get the problem anymore.

**HTML**

```
<%= link_to "Get Paid to Answer Questions", "/the-deal", id: "the_deal", class: "btn btn-link" %>
<h1 id="heading">In-Depth Reviews of Colleges</h1>
<div class="tabbable">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="columbia">
            <%= image_tag "columbia1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "columbia2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "columbia3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Columbia &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/columbia/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How does the workload impact your social life?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "columbia_social_atmosphere_7.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/columbia/social-life/social-atmosphere/7', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="princeton">
            <%= image_tag "princeton1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "princeton2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "princeton3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Princeton &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/princeton/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How would you make your classes better?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "princeton_classes_6.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/princeton/academics/classes/6', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="brown">
            <%= image_tag "brown1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "brown2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "brown3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Brown &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/brown/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Are people intellectual? Do they have thoughtful conversations with each other?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "brown_social_atmosphere_5.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/brown/social-life/social-atmosphere/5', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="penn">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Penn &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/university-of-pennsylvania/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Are your classes too hard, or too easy? Why?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "penn_dificulty_4.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/university-of-pennsylvania/academics/difficulty/4', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="yale">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "yale1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "yale2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "yale3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Yale &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/yale/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Is it easy to make friends? How did you make friends?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "yale_social_atmosphere_1.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/yale/social-life/social-atmosphere/1', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cornell">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "cornell1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "cornell2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "cornell3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Cornell &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/cornell/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Mary Donlon Hall</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "cornell_housing_mary_donlon_hall.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/cornell/living-environment/housing/mary-donlon-hall', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="harvard">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "harvard1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "harvard2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "harvard3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Harvard &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/harvard/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Are there comfortable places to study?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "harvard_campus_2.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/harvard/academics/classes/5', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dartmouth">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "dartmouth1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "dartmouth2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "dartmouth3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Dartmouth &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/dartmouth/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Do professors make things easy to understand?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "dartmouth_professors_1.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/dartmouth/academics/professors/1', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pitt">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pittsburgh1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pittsburgh2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pittsburgh3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Pitt &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Neuroscience: What are people in the major like? How would you stereotype them?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "pitt_neuroscience_8.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/university-of-pittsburgh/academics/majors/neuroscience/8', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="wisconsin">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "university-of-wisconsin1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-wisconsin2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-wisconsin3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Wisconsin &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/university-of-wisconsin/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How much will not partying limit your social life?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "wisconsin_parties_3.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/university-of-wisconsin/social-life/parties/3', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="colgate">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "colgate1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "colgate2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "colgate3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Colgate &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/colgate/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Who wouldn't fit in?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "colgate_social_atmosphere_2.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/colgate/social-life/social-atmosphere/2', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="adelphi">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "adelphi-university1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "adelphi-university2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "adelphi-university3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Adelphi &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/adelphi-university/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How's the on-campus food (taste, price, health, convenience, hours, variety...)?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "adelphi_food_1.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/adelphi-university/living-environment/food/1', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="left" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li id="columbia" class="active"><a href="#columbia">Columbia</a></li>
        <li id="princeton"><a href="#princeton">Princeton</a></li>
        <li id="brown"><a href="#brown">Brown</a></li>
        <li id="penn"><a href="#penn">Penn</a></li>

        <li id="yale"><a href="#yale">Yale</a></li>
        <li id="cornell"><a href="#cornell">Cornell</a></li>
        <li id="harvard"><a href="#harvard">Harvard</a></li>
        <li id="dartmouth"><a href="#dartmouth">Dartmouth</a></li>

        <li id="pitt"><a href="#pitt">Pitt</a></li>
        <li id="wisconsin"><a href="#wisconsin">Wisconsin</a></li>
        <li id="colgate"><a href="#colgate">Colgate</a></li>
        <li id="adelphi"><a href="#adelphi">Adelphi</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="notify">
    <p>Right now I only have reviews for those 12 schools. Enter your email below to be notified when there's more!</p>
    <span id="notify_span">
        <%= simple_form_for :subscribe, url: 'subscribe' do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'user@domain.com', label: false, required: true %> <br/>
            <%= f.button :submit, "1-Click Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { :disable_with => "Submitting..." } %>
        <% end %>
    </span>     
</div>

<ul id="bottom_links">
    <li><%= link_to "I Graduated High School. Now What?", "/i-graduated-high-school-now-what" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "How to Choose a College", "/how-to-choose-a-college" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "How College Inside View Got Started", "https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/322e8668ed6f" %></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('#columbia > a, #princeton > a, #brown > a, #penn > a, #harvard > a, #yale > a, #cornell > a, #dartmouth > a, #pitt > a, #wisconsin > a, #colgate > a, #adelphi > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

**CSS**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "animations";

#home_css {
    max-height: 1200px !important;
    #the_deal {
        float: right;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #heading {
        font-size: 42px;
        clear: right;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .tab-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        .tab-pane {
            .picture {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .school_link {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: beige;
                margin-top: -5px;
                padding: 3px 0px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .right {
                float: right;
                clear: both;
                width: 490px;
                height: 590px;
                .question {
                    position: relative;
                    left: 15px;
                }
                .answers{
                }
                .read_more {
                    display: block;
                    position: relative;
                    left: 15px;
                    top: 10px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #left {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        width: 380px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 590px;
        height: 590px;
    }
    #notify, #bottom_links {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 575px;
    }
    #notify {
        clear: both;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        border-top: 2px solid lightgray;
        border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
        p {
            font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
        }
        #notify_span {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 25px;
            form {
                height: 44px;
            }
            input[type=email] {
                width: 400px;
                height: 35px;
                font-family: monospace;
                font-size: 20px;
                position: relative;
                right: 85px;
            }
            .btn-primary {
                height: 43px;
                width: 137px;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 85px;
                left: 215px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }
    }
    #bottom_links {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: -1000px;
        li {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 60px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the IDs in your JS instead of a common class?

Comment: My guess is that your code is interpreting the URL as code, it _looks_ like a RegExp, but it's not hence that Syntax Error. Can you post the unminified code?

Comment: @coreyward I was just following [bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) and wasn't thinking. I'll add a common class. Thanks!

Comment: @Halcyon what code would you like me to post? I posted what I thought was the relevant HTML, CSS and JS. I'm using Rails btw.

Comment: @AdamZerner The code that triggers when you click the _"Read more about X"_ links

Comment: @Halcyon right. I have no clue why that happens though.

Comment: @coreyward Fixing that seems to solve the problem. Could you write that up as the answer?

Comment: @AdamZerner Chances are you just had an old version in cache that you were looking at, because it worked for all of us before you even made the change.

Comment: @TylerH Oh ok. What exactly does that mean? I know a little bit about how caching works, but I don't understand. Like I know that `js` and `css` files could be cached, but how does it apply here?

Comment: Well, if you had a version that wasn't working for those three links, and you made a change and saved it/shared it with us, we would see the latest version because we haven't visited the site before. You have visited the site plenty, probably, as you're working on it constantly. This means the browser might have cached (saved) a specific version of the site and wasn't showing you the latest, fixed version. It wasn't until you changed some referencing code behind how the site works that the browser updated the cache for you. This is my guess.

Comment: @TylerH So the actual HTML files could be cached? Anyway, for the version that doesn't work on my computer, when I inspect element, this is the code I get: `<a class="school_link" href="/columbia/academics/professors/1">• • Read more about Columbia • •</a>`. So it looks like it's rendering valid code.

Comment: @AdamZerner It was just a guess on my part, since it was working for everyone else, the problem was most likely on your end somehow. The most likely kind of error like that would be caching somewhere.

Comment: Ok. Should I delete this question, or ask someone to write up an answer?

Comment: @AdamZerner clicking on the read more about columbia/princeton/brown is in fact, not working for me... the ones that work appear to have a div with class="left_pane" inside of the div with id=college_short_name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your html between your working and not working divs is different.

```
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="columbia">
            <%= image_tag "columbia1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "columbia2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "columbia3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Columbia &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/columbia/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How does the workload impact your social life?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "columbia_social_atmosphere_7.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/columbia/social-life/social-atmosphere/7', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="princeton">
            <%= image_tag "princeton1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "princeton2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "princeton3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Princeton &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/princeton/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>How would you make your classes better?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "princeton_classes_6.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/princeton/academics/classes/6', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="brown">
            <%= image_tag "brown1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "brown2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= image_tag "brown3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
            <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Brown &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/brown/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Are people intellectual? Do they have thoughtful conversations with each other?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "brown_social_atmosphere_5.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/brown/social-life/social-atmosphere/5', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Above are the ones that do not work.
Below is the first one that does.

```
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="penn">
            <div class="left_pane"> 
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania1.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania2.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= image_tag "university-of-pennsylvania3.jpg", size: "297x187", class: 'picture' %>
                <%= link_to "&bull; &bull; Read more about Penn &bull; &bull;".html_safe, "/university-of-pennsylvania/academics/professors/1", class: 'school_link' %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p class="question" class="well"><strong>Are your classes too hard, or too easy? Why?</strong></p>
                <%= image_tag "penn_dificulty_4.png", class: 'answers' %>
                <%= link_to '--read more--', '/university-of-pennsylvania/academics/difficulty/4', class: 'read_more' %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

A quick comparison between the two tells me that the structure of the colleges that do work is like this

```
<div id="columbia">
  <div class="left_pane" >
    <a>relevant link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right" >
  </div>
</div>
```

While the sections that do not work are structured like this

```
<div id="columbia">
  <a>relevant link</a>
  <div class="right" >
  </div>
</div>
```

This difference in structure appears to be messing up some javascript selectors on your page.  I don't see anything in the code you posted that would be messed up by this structure difference, but I do not think it is a coincidence...

Even if you do change the structure to use classes instead of ids (a good choice in my opinion), it is probably a good idea to figure out what exactly was getting tripped up over this difference in structure, as it may cause other problems later on.

Comment: I can confirm that changing the structure of columbia so that the imgs and the anchor tag are inside of a .left_pane div does cause that anchor to behave as expected... hope that helps

Comment: also, it occurs to me that your tab-panes might be a good choice for a css-only implementation... If you remove that bit of javascript that you have, then I think .tab-pane:not(:target) would be a valid css selector for everything aside from the currently selected tab...

Comment: Ahhh I can't believe I missed that! Thanks.

Comment: @AdamZerner It happens, I spent the better part of yesterday trying to figure out why something wasn't working... only to realize later that I was missing a set of {}s